# Prebuilt entities are not mapping to utterances when exporting model using LUIS Programmatic API

Tags: azure-language-understanding

When I am trying to export a LUIS model which has pre-built entities, the pre-built entities are not annotating in the utterance. I am getting the following JSON payload as the response to the [Export Model API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40)

---

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "2.1.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "SampleApp",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "testintent"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [],
  "bing_entities": [
    "age",
    "datetimeV2",
    "email",
    "number",
    "url"
  ],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "i want to go to beach tomorrow",
      "intent": "testintent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "my age is 22 years old",
      "intent": "testintent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "a is 5 % to less compared to b",
      "intent": "testintent",
      "entities": []
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Here take the example of "***i want to go to beach tomorrow***" utterance. I have marked tomorrow as a `DateTime.V2` entity. But in the exported model the `DateTime.V2` entity is coming as a blank JSON array as compared to the annotated entity.

**Here is my annotated utterances view**
[image]

---

**Here is my entities view**

[image]

---

**Here is the GET request for exporting the model:**
`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/ced3182d-12bb-4961-a163-63dff5cdf47a/versions/0.1/export`

Headers:
**Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** - **a182de82cd23473a96682e09ceb56536**

---

**Can someone tell me the reason for this?** 
Is there any way to get annotated prebuilt entities in the following way:

```
{
      "text": "i want to go to beach tomorrow",
      "intent": "testintent",
      "entities": [
                   {
                      "entity": "builtin.datetime.v2",
                      "startPos": 22,
                      "endPos":   29
                   }
                  ]
}
```

Comment: Trivial question but... are you exporting the right version of your LUIS App?

Comment: Yes, I am exporting the correct version of the LUIS app

Comment: And do you have the same export content while exporting from the UI?

Comment: @NicolasR yes the exact same content

Comment: Last thing: can you export, reimport with a different version number, train, and then test and see if your prebuilt entities are detected? I wonder if this `Labeled utterances` is useful for prebuilt entites...

Comment: I tried doing that, but no closure :(

Comment: Any update? Could you answer your own question if you solved it or else provide some additional insights to help resolve it ? :)

Comment: @LittleTiger No, sadly Microsoft does not provide the API for querying the builtin entities. It just magically appears in the `LuisResult` object somehow.